# Insert into Database using form in Netbeans 7.01

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing an individual project in java. I want to insert data into my database...but my              program is successfully running without any error but when insert data and submit the my      data it will give an error like this java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().This My Code: \
what can do for solved this problem

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


  if (evt.getSource() == jButton1)``
     {
        int x = 0;
        String s1 = jTextField1.getText().trim();
        String s2 = jTextField2.getText();
        char[] s3 = jPasswordField1.getPassword();
        char[] s4 = jPasswordField2.getPassword(); 
        String s8 = new String(s3);
        String s9 = new String(s4);

        String s5 = jTextField5.getText();
        String s6 = jTextField6.getText();
        String s7 = jTextField7.getText();

 if(s8.equals(s9))
        {
            try{



        File image = new File(filename);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {

            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
        }
        cat_image = bos.toByteArray();

                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into reg values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                 ps.setString(1,s1);
                 ps.setString(2,s2);
                 ps.setString(3,s8);
                 ps.setString(4,s5);
                 ps.setString(5,s6);
                 ps.setString(6,s7);
                 ps.setBytes(7,cat_image);

                 rs = ps.executeQuery();
                 if(rs.next())
                 {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data insert Succesfully");
                 }else
                 {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Password Dosn't match" ,"Acces dinied",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                 }


            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Use `ps.executeUpdate()`  or just only `ps.execute()`.

Comment: Kk I have done its successfully done tnx ur answers

Comment: Click the green checkmark under the post, on the left. (I think it's right below the arrows). In that way this post is solved.

Comment: @nachokk tnx its woking for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ps.executeUpdate()` or `ps.execute()`.

From [executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29)

> **Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as
>   INSERT**, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing,
>   such as a DDL statement.

From [execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29)

> **Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which
>   may be any kind of SQL statement**. Some prepared statements return
>   multiple results; the execute method handles these complex statements
>   as well as the simpler form of statements handled by the methods
>   executeQuery and executeUpdate.The execute method returns a boolean to
>   indicate the form of the first result. You must call either the method
>   getResultSet or getUpdateCount to retrieve the result; you must call
>   getMoreResults to move to any subsequent result(s).

Then modify your code properly

```
int rowsAffected = ps.executeUpdate();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Rows Inserted "+ rowsAffected);
```

Also you have to close your streams and connections in a finally block.

Comment: Thanks a lot I have done...it's working successfully

Answer (score 0):

SQLException is thrown because of wrong sql statement. You may have syntax error while inserting string and integer values. Check your sql statement after VALUES there should be "1-0" around integer elements and '"some value"' around string elements.